# Can't bring back old mysql on mac

Tags: mac, mysql, database, mariadb

Initial problem is when I try to run `mysql` on terminal it outputs something like this:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (61)
```

I was triying to install `MariaDb` and for that I installed `DBngin` app. I think, it created a separete version of `MySql`. I uninstalled `DBngin` and now I am trying to uninstall `MySql` via homebrew but it is working in the backgroud even after uninstalling via `homebrew`. I also uninstalled `MariaDb` and as of now I'm just triying to bring back my old `MySql` with its data.

After uninstalling when I type mysql to command line it is not finding the command. That's normal right? But when I type `brew services info mysql` it's showing that mysql is running:

```
mysql (homebrew.mxcl.mysql)
Running: ✘
Loaded: ✔
Schedulable: ✘
```

Then I started to search the pid of that mysql process. I tried to find it via `ps -A | grep mysql | awk '{print $1}'` command and it print out the number, right now it is `6407`. But when I tried to kill that process via `kill -9 6407` command, it says: `kill: kill 6407 failed: no such process`. That's because every time pid number is changing.

So as a wrap up, I think I have two versions of mysql and probably they are overlaping. I have all my old databases with folder names inside of `/opt/homebrew/var/mysql` folder and after installation of mysql via homebrew it creates this `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql/8.3.0_1` also.

https://imgur.com/a/nWuLZQ2